# file path doesn't work on Mac OS X

Tags: c, macos, file, fopen

So, that's the main code, that should print a .txt file:

```
int main (void){
FILE *arq= fopen("/Users/bruno/AED/EPLista/Loremipsum.txt", "r");
int c;
if(arq == NULL)
    printf("Erro, não foi possivel abrir o arquivo\n");
else
while((c=fgetc(arq)) != EOF){
    printf("%c", (char) c);
}
fclose(arq);
```

But all I get is the message from that if, saying that the file can't be open...

I'm running CodeBlocks 13.12 on a Mac OS X Yosemite

Does anyone know what can it be?

Comment: Works fine for me! Please check the permissions on the file!

Comment: I guess that means the file is somewhere else. Try again with an absolute path. Also, `fgetc()` returns an `int` value. Forcing it into a `char` container may make it impossible to detect the `EOF`. Use `int c;` instead.

Comment: What does your title "Returning -1 on main" mean? It doesn't seem to be related to the body of your question.  And please update your question to show a complete program; you're missing at least `#include <stdio.h>` at the top and `}` at the bottom. Also, don't call `fclose` with a null pointer argument.